# controller spec failing with ActionController::RoutingError with get method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, rspec-rails

I am building a Rails 3 application, and I am a little confused with a controller spec. here what I have in the application:

#### routes.rb

```
get "/:user_name/library", :to => 'users#library', :as => :user_library
```

#### users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def library
    end
end
```

#### users_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "UsersController" do
    describe "#library" do
        let(:user){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
        it "renders the users/library.html.erb view" do
            get :library, :parameters => {:user_name => user.user_name}
        end
    end
end
```

this example dose not run and it shows the following error

```
Failure/Error: get :library,:parameters => {:user_name => user.user_name}
ActionController::RoutingError:
    No route matches {:parameters=>{:user_name=>"UserName"}, :controller=>"users", :action=>"library"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `:parameters` key in your `get`:

```
get :library, :user_name => user.user_name
```